# Returning validation errors as JSON with Play! framework

Tags: java, ajax, json, validation, playframework

I want to build an application where forms are submitted via Ajax without a complete page reload. To display server-side validation errors the server should return validation errors as JSON and an appropriate HTTP status (400).

How can I accomplish this with the Play! framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something more complex than this:

```
public static void yourControllerMethod() {
    ... // your validation logic

    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
       response.status = 400;
       renderJSON(validation.errors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Play Framework 2.x and Scala you can use this example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class LoginData(email : String, password: String)

implicit object FormErrorWrites extends Writes[FormError] {
  override def writes(o: FormError): JsValue = Json.obj(
    "key" -> Json.toJson(o.key),
    "message" -> Json.toJson(o.message)
  )
}

val authForm = Form[LoginData](mapping(
  "auth.email" -> email.verifying(Constraints.nonEmpty),
  "auth.password" -> nonEmptyText
  )(LoginData.apply)(LoginData.unapply))

def registerUser = Action { implicit request =>
 authForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  form => UnprocessableEntity(Json.toJson(form.errors)),
  auth => Ok(Json.toJson(List(auth.email, auth.password)))
 )
}
```

I see that question is labeled with java tag, but I suppose this maybe useful for Scala developers.

Comment: The import statements for the above should include `import play.api.libs.json._` and the implicit object could most likely exist in your controller as a reusable entity as you are converting form errors (note the form DOT errors) and not anything unique to the case class itself. More than obvious once you know all this but stackoverflow is to help those that don't :)

Comment: Thanks for tips, I have added import.

Answer (score 6):

To perform server side validation of your request, Play framework provides a builtin validation module which uses [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) under the hood.

Assuming you have a POJO class corresponding to the incoming request,

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
    public class UserRequest{       
    @Constraints.Required
    private String userName;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String email;
}
```

The request validation can be performed from controller as follows.

```
public class UserController extends Controller{
Form<UserRequest> requestData = Form.form(UserRequest.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(requestData.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(requestData.errorsAsJson());
    } else{
        //... successful validation
    }
}
```

The following response will be produced if the request fails the validation.

```
{
  "userName": [
    "This field is required"
  ],
  "email": [
    "This field is required"
  ]
}
```

In addition to this, you can apply multiple Constraints to the class fields. Some of them are,

- @Constraints.Min()
- @Constraints.Max()
- @Constraints.Email

Answer (score 4):

Look at the samples-and-tests folder and the validation application. One of the examples (Sample7), does exactly what you are after, using a custom tag called jQueryValidate (which you can see in the sample).

If you try the sample, you will see that it is quite a neat solution, and in my opinion, this validation method should be part of the Core Playframework.